# DataBindings.Add using IFormatProvider

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I am trying to use an IFormatProvider to customize some databindings; however the IFormatProvider class is never being called. I put breakpoints at the begining of both functions in my custom formating class and neither are being hit through databinding. When I use my custom formating class with String.Format it works.

I am using .Net 2.0 and winforms.

This is how I do the data bindings:

```
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox1, "Text", true, 
                            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, 
                "<NULL>","{0:H}",new MyFormat());
```

This is how I used String.Format:

```
string test =(string.Format(_superFormat, "{0}", "this is my arg"));
```

And this is my custom formating class:

```
    class MyFormat : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        string ICustomFormatter.Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            string result = ((string)arg).ToUpper();
            return result ;
        }
        object IFormatProvider.GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
                return this;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Assuming the `Text` property is a string, then as far as I know it *can't* use a formatter, because `string` doesn't implement `IFormattable`.

The `Binding` class (which underpins `DataBindings.Add`) has a [`Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format.aspx) event and [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) event that can be used to control formatting. You can also use a `TypeConverter` on the target bound property, which I like because it moves this logic away from the UI.

So: do you have an example of what you want to do?

Comment: His problem is pretty clear. He supplies a custom formatter to DataBindigs.Add, and WinForms completely ignores it, never calling GetFormat() or Format(). I have the same problem, and wonder why it is possible to specify a formatter when it is not actually used.